# Why did Tris not die from failing the Amity simulation when she tackled Jenine?

Tags: divergent, insurgent

In the movie, it seems to me a subtle truth that the simulation kills people when they outright fail the simulation. Meaning, if someone is, say Abnegation and Amity, but not any of the others, when those tests come, they will fail the simulation, and also consequently die.

However, it seems tempting to say that amity shouldn't fight when there's not a right to do so because of course you know the definition of amity structures how people of that faction should behave. This makes sense because alternatively, you know that Tris did fight and even hurt people-but her intentions changed everything. She didn't want to hurt people, but did what she had to to live. Or else, how could she be Amity?

So, while there's not a completely logical correlation between the previous observation and the statement: "because what Jenine said about Tris's family deaths being futile was a lie, Tris wasn't completely wrong in attacking Jenine", is it reasonable to conclude that Tris didn't die in the simulation when she fell because of exactly that reason?

Comment: Tris is a super human, if you read the books she is basically a super divergent. shes regularly shown to be able to over come things other divergent cant, which is one of the reason Jenine studies her.

Comment: In Matrix terms, she is The One.

Answer (score 3):

Tris does almost die and it's only because Jeanine reluctantly stops the sim after being told by Caleb that Tris' life signs are dropping.

The fact that Tris is a 100% divergent and the ideal candidate for the sims is the likely explanation that failure of a sim didn't outright kill her.

Comment: what does it mean that Tris is a 100% divergent?

Answer (score 1):

Remember when Tris got taken out of the sim when they saw she was tired? After she rested and they finally wrestled her to her feet and down the hall, that one kid that keeps switching sides gave her a shot to slow down her vitals. Therefore when she failed the sim, she was already had a weak pulse. She was in a "death" like state if you will. After that, her pulse started to return to normal and she woke up.

Answer (score 1):

If you noticed when Tris started to fight against the guards, Peter injected Tris with a serum to calm her down. Tris later failed the Amity sim, so she died. She did die momentarily. When brought in front of Tobias/Four's cell, the guards flip back the sheet to reveal a dead Tris. The guards bring Tobias/Four out of his cell, where he is held from running at them. Peter asks him to break free. Tris later starts breathing. Peter explains that he injected Tris with a paralytic serum, which caused her to "die". Tris is very much alive, but I haven't finished the whole movie. Hope that clears it up :)